# Is a quantum state with coefficient 0 still there?

Tags: quantum-state, measurement

Potentially stupid question but is a quantum state with a zero coefficient still there? I didn't think it was but then I saw in the answer to a problem that when we measure

$$
\hat{M} = |1\rangle \langle 1 |
$$

On a state

$$
|\psi\rangle = \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}(|0\rangle + |1\rangle)
$$

We measure value $1$ with probability $0.5$ and value $0$ with probability $0.5$. If we measured $1$, it is clear that the state is now

$$
|\psi\rangle = 1 \cdot|1\rangle = |1\rangle
$$

But if we measured value 0, is the state now in

$$
|\psi\rangle = 0 \cdot|0\rangle = ?
$$

The state collapsed to $| 0 \rangle$ but the coefficient is zero, so there is a 50% chance the state is just destroyed?

I thought I understood this and was happy with the conclusion that $| \psi \rangle = 0$ but in the answer to a question it said that after measurement we have a 50% chance of being in $|0 \rangle$ and 50% chance of being in $|1 \rangle$ which left me confused as to if the $|0\rangle$ state was actually there

Answer (score 1):

The state after measuring 0 is $|0\rangle$ times an arbitrary nonzero complex number. In other words, it's the ray in Hilbert space that includes $|0\rangle$.

The number assigned to the measurement outcome doesn't figure into the post-measurement collapse. It has no meaning at all: you can use any two distinct real numbers in place of 0 and 1.

Answer (score 0):

Do not confuse unitary operator and quantum operator in general.

Some quantum operators can transform a qubit state into $0$. For example, the Hamiltonian $\mathcal{H}$ is an operator, you can take expectation values $\langle x|\mathcal{H}|x\rangle$, and yes sometimes it can be zero (for some state $|x\rangle$, sometimes $\mathcal H|x\rangle=0$). Another example is your projector $M=|1\rangle\langle1|$.

Unitary operators are those that define a change of basis and are the only allowed in the evolution of your states (thus quantum gates are always unitary, see also [unitary evolution operator](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unitarity_(physics))). These operators can never change a pure state into zero.

A unitary operator for a single qubit can be for example the Hadamard operation $H$ (not to be confused with the Hamiltonian above). $H$ represents a change of basis, for example $H|0\rangle=|+\rangle$ and $H|1\rangle=|-\rangle$ where $|\pm\rangle=\frac{1}{\sqrt 2} (|0\rangle+|1\rangle)$. Note that there is no qubit state $|x\rangle$ such that $H|x\rangle=0$.